# How to enumerate cookies in OWIN ResponseCookieCollection

Tags: c#, cookies, owin, katana

I need to delete all cookies whose name starts with a certain prefix. But the [`Microsoft.Owin.ResponseCookieCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.responsecookiecollection(v=vs.111).aspx) is not enumerable. Do I need to query the underlying OWIN structures?

How can I get the keys for all cookies starting with a prefix and delete them?

Answer (score 2):

I need to either sleep more or drink more coffee. The collection I wanted to enumerate was `Microsoft.Owin.RequestCookieCollection`, which is enumerable.